# How do I upload html5 banner to DFP?

Tags: html5, google-dfp

How do I upload html5 banner to DFP?

I read an article [How to prepare HTML5 assets for DCM](https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/3145300?hl=en#zip)

It needs to upload zip file to DFP.

> To set up display creatives with HTML5 and HTML5 banners, upload your
>   HTML5 creative to DCM in the form of a .zip file. The .zip should
>   consist of an HTML file plus any files referenced by the HTML file.

I tried to upload zip file,
In 'add creative' section, choose "Image animation",
but there is not section to upload zip file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Admin" to enable "API access"
Then go to site html5-to-dfp.appspot.com to upload the html5 zip file.